# ERROR: While executing gem (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError) SSL_read: Wrong version number

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, windows-7-x64

I installed Ruby 2.2.2 x64 and gem version 2.4.6. on Windows 7 64
I've run `gem update --system`
I get the above error when doing `gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc`

I've researched Google, but found no relevant answer. Any ideas?

Comment: I reinstalled the Devkit. Didn't run an update. ran 'gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc' and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

RailsInstaller is the best package for installing rails on windows.It includes all required Packages. RilasInstaller - http://railsinstaller.org/en